# Can't install packages in Sublime 3

Tags: sublime-text

I installed Sublime 3, and the package manager. Strangely enough it doesn't work. I can't install packages. It worked when I installed it, but after the last Ubuntu upgrade no more. When I go to Package Control > Install Package I see sublime Loading Repositories at the bottom line, but that's it. It stops after a few seconds.

I tried to manually install the package I want, but that doesn't seem to work either, likely because I do something wrong: 
1- create the folder (Less) in the opt/sublime_text/packages/Less
2- Paste the files in that folder from https://github.com/danro/Less-sublime

I know I do something completely wrong, but I have no idea what.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the package manager yet?

Comment: Yes. Actually, I removed Sublime completely, reinstalled it, then removed the package manager and lastly reinstalled that one. Now I can see the error message:

Comment: Exception in thread Thread-24:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./threading.py", line 901, in _bootstrap_inner

Comment: File "package_control.commands.install_package_command in /home/jos/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/Package Control.sublime-package", line 43, in run
  File "package_control.package_installer in /home/jos/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/Package Control.sublime-package", line 54, in make_package_list
  File "package_control.package_manager in /home/jos/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/Package Control.sublime-package", line 260, in list_available_packages
  File "package_control.downloaders.background_downloader in

Comment: /home/jos/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/Package Control.sublime-package", line 52, in get_provider
KeyError: 'https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LESS'

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I tried this. The code is too long for one comment.

Comment: After restarting Sublime the package manager works. But the package I want to install throws an error:
Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2015-07-11 13:26:28, next run at 2015-07-11 14:26:28 or after
Package Control: Error parsing JSON from channel https://github.com/danro/LESS-sublime.git.
Package Control: Error parsing JSON from repository https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LESS.
Package Control: Error parsing JSON from repository https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Less2Css.
ignored packages updated to: ["Vintage", "LESS"]

Comment: and you are trying to get Less2css installed?

Comment: If you go into user settings and delete `,"LESS"` from the ignore list does it work then